# There are no touchpad settings in Ubuntu 18.10 installed in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, touchpad, tap-to-click

In `Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad` I only see settings for a mouse, when I am using a touchpad. This prevents me from middle clicking with a 3 finger tap on my touchpad which is a critical function for someone who spends a great deal of time working at the terminal.

How can I get Ubuntu 18.10 to recognize my Touch Pad? Installing `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` as recommended other places did not help. It still treats it as a mouse, but not being an actual mouse, but being a touch pad, I can't middle click or simultaneously left and right click.

`xinput` shows the following...

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VirtualBox mouse integration              id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VirtualBox USB Tablet                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu in VirtualBox?

Comment: Yes Ubuntu 18.10 Virtualbox 6.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualBox has limited direct access to hardware.

That is why your touchpad can't be managed by a full-feature driver with multitouch capabilities.

You need to install Ubuntu directly for a full-feature touchpad. But that doesn't guarantee that the specific touchpad is fully supported by Linux kernel.

Comment: So I am basically waiting for virtualbox updates to get better touchpad support?

Comment: I don't think VB will support this soon.